# Passing a datagridview value to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking to pass a datagridview value to another form for editing. I can find a lot of examples for code behind, but I can't really seem to find an example that takes this code out of the code behind.

My example code

```
ProductView productView = new ProductView();

productview.txtbox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox4.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
productview.ShowDialog();
```

Is this something that is allowed to put in the code behind? 
I try to put as little as possible code behind, only the necessary things.

Comment: What do you mean be "put as little as possible in the code behind"? Where else would you put your code?

Comment: I try to put as much as possible in my presenter/controller/... But this situation i have no clue what to do with

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define "allowed". It works so compiler and .NET framework allowed for this, but is it a good practice ? Well you need to pass it somehow but let's start from the beggining

1. Do not name your TextBoxes like "textbox1" etc. Give them a name which actaully means something  like "tbName" or "nameTextbox" or anything which is self explantatory.
2. If ProductView Form is made exclusivly for showing this details i would create a constructor for this class which accepts exactly those parameteres(preferably as a class).
   So for instance i would create a new class in some separated project like below.

.

```
public class ProductViewOptions
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And later on in ProductView form create a private property of above type and create a constructor accepting argument of this type. It could look like below:

```
public class ProductView : Form
{
    private ProductViewOptions productOptions;
    public ProductView(ProductViewOptions ProductOptions)
    {
         this.productOptions = ProductOptions;
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks to this your code would be much more readable and your example would look like this:

```
ProductViewOptions productOptions = new ProductViewOptions ();
productOptions.ProductName = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
productOptions.ProductPrice = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

ProductView productView = new ProductView(productOptions);
productView.ShowDialog();
```

The new piece of code is self explantatory and easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you set your DataGridView SelectionMode = FullRowSelect, you can achieve it this way:

```
ProductView productView = new ProductView();
productview.txtbox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["columnName1"].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["columnName2"].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["columnName3"].Value.ToString();
productview.txtbox4.Text = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["columnName4"].Value.ToString();
productview.ShowDialog();
```